# Cannot attach click handler to anchor class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've got the following html code:

```
<div id="menuItems" class="hidden">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="fgMenuItem" href="#">MenuItem #1</a></li>
        <li>
            <a class="fgMenuItem" href="#">MenuItem #2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="fgMenuItem" href="#">SubItem #1</a></li>
                <li><a class="fgMenuItem" href="#">SubItem #2</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a class="fgMenuItem" href="#">MenuItem #3</a></li>
         <li>
            <a class="fgMenuItem" href="#">MenuItem #4</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="fgMenuItem" href="#">SubItem #3</a></li>
                <li><a class="fgMenuItem" href="#">SubItem #4</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
     </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".fgMenuItem").bind("click",function() {
            alert('test');
        });            
    });
</script>
```

I'm using [Filament Group's iPod menu](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ipod_style_and_flyout_menus/) and the menus are working fine, but my jQuery code is not working. I'm trying to make it so that when an item is clicked, it executes my `alert('test');`.

I suspect the problem may be that Filament Group is overriding my click event handler, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I tried going into their javascript file and changing all the `.click(function() {` to `.bind("click", function() {`, but this didn't seem to make any difference. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Do you get any console errors on the event?

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall -- No, I don't. That was the first thing I checked for.

Comment: Can you replicate the problem using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @Dom -- Try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jv584/1/)

Comment: @icemanind I am getting Forbidden 403 error. Might be the cause of your problem.

Comment: @Dom -- Try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jv584/2/) instead. I linked the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested and all working fine for me, you are including jQuery at the top of your document right?

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">  </script>
</head>

$(function() {
    $(".fgMenuItem").on("click",function() {
        alert('test');
    });            
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jv584/

EDIT: If you're able to set up a fiddle or provide more code (working demo page perhaps?) then I'll take another look and see if I can spot the problem

Comment: Try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jv584/1/). I updated yours and now it stopped working.

Comment: That won't work because we're trying to call the method menu when it isn't defined, i'm guessing that's in the other JS file you're including?

Comment: Yes, it is. I have an external resource that is added to my fiddle.

Comment: It's not linked up properly therefore still getting the same issue. The JS link is forbidden

Comment: That's weird. It doesn't do that for me. Here [is a link to my external resource](http://filamentgroup.com/examples/menus/fg.menu.js). Try adding it manually